# OpenIddict Issuer validation failed on linux server

Tags: openiddict

OpenIddict based Identity server validates the token in its own [Authorized] Controllers, but it rejects the token when accessed from another Resource Server through /introspect endpoint.

Everything worked fine in the development machine. This is happening after deploying the service to a Linux server  where the services are hosted on different ports of the same machine.

This is the actual exception in my Logs:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'System.String'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'System.String' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'System.String'.
```

The setup is similar to this:
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Zirku/Zirku.Server/Startup.cs

This is my openiddict setup:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
                // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                    .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
            }).AddServer(options =>
            {
                // Enable the authorization, logout, token and userinfo endpoints.
                options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                    .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                    .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                    .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect")
                    .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");
                

                // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                options.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);

                // Note: this sample only uses the authorization code flow but you can enable
                // the other flows if you need to support implicit, password or client credentials.
                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();
                options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();
                options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate();
                //     .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                // Encryption and signing of tokens
                options.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                    .AddEphemeralSigningKey();

                options.RegisterScopes(ApplicationConstants.MobileApiResource);

                options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                options.SetIdentityTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
                options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                options.UseAspNetCore()
                    //todo remove the disable transport layer security
                    .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement()
                    .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                    .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                    .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                    .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                    .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();

                options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
            })
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
               options.UseLocalServer();
                // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });
```

This is the setup on my API:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
        
        services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                // Note: the validation handler uses OpenID Connect discovery
                // to retrieve the address of the introspection endpoint.
                options.SetIssuer(identityUrl);
                options.AddAudiences("client_id");

                // Configure the validation handler to use introspection and register the client
                // credentials used when communicating with the remote introspection endpoint.
                options.UseIntrospection()
                    .SetClientId("client_id")
                    .SetClientSecret("secret");
                // Register the System.Net.Http integration.
                options.UseSystemNetHttp();

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });
```

Comment: Share your concept and code  tomorrow then I solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, with the help of my senior, we were able to diagnose the issue. This issue was related to nginx.

> The server was only returning the issuer domain address but not the port, itwas returning xyz.com as the issuer instead of the actual issuer address xyz.com:5001

The proper resolution is to adjust the nginx conf proxy's Host header directive.

Changed this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

To this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

also added this to the Startup.cs of the identity server:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
```